# Using a getter with linq, is the data cached?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a console application. Suppose I have a getter that calls a store procedure with Linq to Sql. The store procedure returns `ISingleResult<T>` and is converted to `List<T>`:

```
private List<GetInvoicesResult> _invoiceRequests {             
    get{
        var result = this._context.GetInvoices();                
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result.ToList();
        }
        return null;
    }              
}
```

if I made 2 calls to the getter reference:

```
int ct =  _invoiceRequests.Count();

foreach(var invoice in _invoiceRequests){
   //do something
}
```

is the stored procedure executed twice or do I need to cache the data?

Comment: It can't be cached because the data could change between calls. It would be incorrect.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. cached where? at application? database? CPU? if you are asking whether the code above caches, no it doesnt.

Comment: Caching would violate POLA.

Comment: @JeffBridgman what is POLA?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/07/01/linq-to-sql-tips-9-understanding-datacontext-s-internal-caching.aspx

Comment: @DarthVader [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) = Principle of Least Astonishment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will execute the SP twice.  If you want to cache the data you'll need to do that explicitly in your property getter.